# Expanding gridview's row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

One of gridview's column is a "Content" column that can have few lines of text (it can be literal, textbox or label ).

In "default" mode i want it to show only the first line and a link button: "(more)" or "(read)".

Clicking on this link should expand the column and display full content.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting first 10 characters of content text and using it as your link's text is better aproach. This will reduce size of data that retrieved from database like that :

```
SELECT ContentId, SUBSTRING(Content, 0, 10) AS Content
FROM ContentTable;
```

Then you can use template column for this column that includes a label and a link. Lbel for the description text, link for the details.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>

   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label
           Text='<%# Eval("Content") %>'
           runat="server"/>
      <a href='<%# Eval("ContentId", "contentdetails.aspx?id={0}") %>'>More</a>
   </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I am already filling gridview via ObjectDataSource and use '<%# Eval("Content") %>' to get the full content.
Can I trim the content before it's being inserted?

Comment: Then you have a property for content ? you can trim content at the getter of the property.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=1465

Answer (score 0):

try this. http://mosesofegypt.net/post/BuildingjQueryAndASPNetAJAXEnabledControlsjQueryCollapsiblePanelExtenderPart2.aspx

Comment: I believe you can do it with out ajax too.. if that looks similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of CSS!

Place this inside your gridview row. It will naturally push out the row to the height of your content, or the amount of rows required.

```
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="toggle-header">
    Toggle!
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-height">
    <div class="toggle-transform">
      <p>2nd line of text</p>
      <p>3rd line</p>
      <p>4th line</p>
      <p>etc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And use this CSS...

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

.toggle-header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-height {
  background-color: tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .6s ease;
  max-height: 0;
}

.toggle:hover .toggle-height {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.toggle-transform {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.toggle:hover .toggle-transform {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

You may want to disguise the "toggle" with a textbox of your "(more)" line to expand the rest.

Let us know if it worked.